# How do I integrate a polynomial to a non-specific constant?

Tags: integration

How do I carry out this integral without having to plug in a definite value for a?
$$ \int{(1-x^2)^a}dx $$
I know that the answer involves a gamma function from plugging it into Mathematica, but I cannot find any way to get there. It might be helpful to know that I started with
$$\int{\sin^{2a+1}(x)} dx $$
and did a u-sub to get here.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please have a look at [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/695196). You'll find that questions of the form "Here's a problem statement, solve it for me" are not well received and will likely attract downvotes. To solve this, please add context to your question: Where did the problem come from? Why do you want to solve it? What did you try before? Where exactly did you get stuck? etc.

Comment: Since you say that the answer involves the Gamma function, you're probably interested in the _definite_ integral $\int_{-1}^{1} (1-x^2)^{a}\mathrm{d}x$. This is important because I don't think the general indefinite integral you wrote in your question has a nicer closed form beyond hypergeometric functions, however, the definite integral _does_ have a simpler answer (which is obtained without using the antiderivative). Useful information like this is the reason why context written in the body of the question is encouraged.

Answer (score 1):

As Robert Lee said, the indefinite integral can’t be expressed by Gamma function. However, adding limits 0 and 1 works as below:
$$
\begin{aligned}
I &=\int_0^1\left(1-\sin ^2 \theta\right)^a \cos \theta d \theta \\
&=\int_0^1 \cos ^{2 a+1} \theta d \theta \\
&=\int_0^1 \sin ^{2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-1} \theta \cos ^{2 a+1} \theta d \theta \\
&=\frac{1}{2} B\left(\frac{1}{2}, a\right) \\
&=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \Gamma(a)}{2\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}+a\right)} \\
&=\frac{\sqrt{\pi} \Gamma(a)}{2\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}+a\right)}
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 0):

You can always regard $\sin^{2a + 1}(x)$ as $\sin^n(x)$.

In this way, I present you two rather useful identities:

$${\displaystyle \sin ^{n}x ={\frac {2}{2^{n}}}\sum _{k=0}^{\frac {n-1}{2}}(-1)^{({\frac {n-1}{2}}-k)}{\binom {n}{k}}\sin {{\big (}(n-2k)x {\big )}}}\quad {\text{when n is odd}}$$
$${\displaystyle \sin ^{n}x ={\frac {1}{2^{n}}}{\binom {n}{\frac {n}{2}}}+{\frac {2}{2^{n}}}\sum _{k=0}^{{\frac {n}{2}}-1}(-1)^{({\frac {n}{2}}-k)}{\binom {n}{k}}\cos {{\big (}(n-2k{\big )}x )}}\quad {\text{when n is even}}$$

In this sense, integrating them is a rather trivial exercise.